# Importing tess-two into an Android project in Intellij

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, tesseract

I've compiled the project using the instructions given [here](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) and am now trying to add it to my Android project.

I've tried adding it as a library, in which case the symbol for class `com.googlecode.android` does not exist.

Also, importing it as a module and depending on that, leading to a lot of libraries not being found within the tess-two module.

So, how do I use tess-two with an existing Android project in the IntelliJ IDE?

(Now a Maven project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.
First i followed these instructions for gradle configuration :
https://coderwall.com/p/eurvaq
It means building with the ndk and ant, then following the instructions, manually adding and editing the guy's build.gradle in android studio, and importing tess-two as a module. 
Only then did i get that error (i also had red crosses on all java src files in the tess-two library), which got solved with good old clean/build.

Comment: I managed to fix it by importing it as a module and deleting the bin dir. It's a dirty fix so I might switch to your version if I have the time.